# Meta key does not open "Activities" menu in Gnome 3

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell

I've started using the Gnome 3 packages that just came through the Debian testing repositories, and encountered a problem.

Hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Meta</kbd>/<kbd>Windows</kbd> key would not open "Activities" menu. Other shortcuts (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc.) work as expected.

Can you help me find the reason (and a solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason and a solution:

In Settings > Region and Language > Layouts > Options there is an option "Behaviour of Alt/Windows-Key". For some reason this was not on "Default" per default (hope you get me).

After I put this option to "Default", everything works as expected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess: Could you have remapped it?  That is, does it show up as `Super_L` (or possibly `Super_R`) when you press the key with window focus in `xev`?

**Edit:**
Also check your logs, probably `~/.xsession-errors`.

**Edit:** There are [lots of bug reports](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=gnome-shell&content=super) concerning gnome-shell and <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Comment: `xev` says `KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0xb0, subw 0x0, time 192228, (267,145), root:(269,266),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffe7, Meta_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False` when I press Super

Comment: oh, ~/.xsession-errors says: `Error:            Meta_L added to symbol map for multiple modifiers
                  Using Mod4, ignoring Mod1.
Error:            Key <META> added to map for multiple modifiers
                  Using Mod4, ignoring Mod1.`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you may need to reassign your  key if using another emulator such as VirtualBox as it defaults to the left  as the hot key also.